# Using excel folder as a database for my windows form, I'm not able to reach the data

Tags: c#, database, excel

I'm pretty new to programming and right now I'm trying to write a invoice maker application for the company I'm working. This is something I'm trying to implement in order to make my tasks easy.

So, there is an excel folder with item numbers and their respective net and gross weights, like this;

> MTS 0001 / 24 / 26
>
> MTS 0002 / 24 / 26
>
> MTS 0003 / 28 / 30
>
> MTS 0008 / 34 / 36

This info is contained in myworkbook.xlsx, Sheet2, so I've implemented a function within Sheet2.cs, like this;

```
public bool FindNetWeight(string item, out int weight)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
        {
            if (Cells[1, i])
            {
                return int.TryParse(Cells[3, i], out weight);
            }
        }
        weight = 0;
        return false;
    }
```

Now, in my Form.cs, which is cs for my windows form, I'm trying to use FindNetWeight, it shows me that I need a String argument and an integer out, but it does not let me use the function and gives me the following error;

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property

What could be the problem here? Hopefully my description is clear enough to follow and I've gave every necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling a non static function from a static one.
You can either make your FindNetWeight static, or create a new Instance of Sheet2.

The simple way is to make it static, so:

```
        public static bool FindNetWeight(string item, out int weight) 
        {
         //yourcode
        }
```

Or, create a new instance of Sheet2:

```
Sheet2 mySheet = new Sheet2();
mySheet.FindNetWeight(blabla)
```

Comment: More information can be found on [Microsoft-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120)